# Jquery set correct usercontrol textbox value to 0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a slight problem accessing a textbox in a user control with jquery.

On my page I have a grid control and on rows 28,29,30 I am populating the cells with the same usercontrol. This is because the user control is used for typing a percentage and in one column the three values cannot exceed 100%.

So if this does happen I want to set the correct textbox values to 0 or change the colour, i.e. the column where the three numbers have exceeded 100%. My problem is I can't access the textbox with jquery.

**Javascript**

```
function percentageCheck(objNetMarginUnitsSoldFullPrice, objNetMarginUnitsSoldMarkdown,  objNetMarginGoodsUnsold) { // pass objects with values
    var percentageCntr = new Array();
    cntrString = '';

    for (var i = 1; i < 15; i++) { // 14 cells in row. Ignore cell 0

        if (i < 11) { // less than logic to build control IDs
            ctrlString = '_ctl0';
        } else {
            ctrlString = '_ctl';
        }

        percentageCntr[0] = objNetMarginUnitsSoldFullPrice[i];
        percentageCntr[1] = objNetMarginUnitsSoldMarkdown[i];
        percentageCntr[2] = objNetMarginGoodsUnsold[i];

        var total = percentageCntr[0] + percentageCntr[1] + percentageCntr[2];

        var result = 0;

        if(total > 100) {
            alert("Cannot exceed 100%");

            alert(i); // See correct int value

//              $('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r28_ctl10_txtPercentage').val(result); Works!

            $('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r' + 28 + ctrlString + i + '_txtPercentage').css('backgroundColor', '#EC3434');
            $('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r' + 29 + ctrlString + i + '_txtPercentage').css('backgroundColor', '#EC3434');
            $('#ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r' + 30 + ctrlString + i + '_txtPercentage').css('backgroundColor', '#EC3434');
        }  
    }
}
```

I have hard coded a jquery selector that works but when I concatenate the whole jquery selector it doesn't work. I also know there is a proper way of accessing a user control with jquery but I am not sure if it will work here.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your jquery for setting background-color is correct

The issue might be as follows -

```
if (i < 11) { // less than logic to build control IDs
            ctrlString = '_ctl0';
        } else {
            ctrlString = '_ctl';
        }
```

Reason if i = 1 the you will get `_ctl01` and dont think so you have control with 01 index

Comment: In my grid cell 0 is row name and cell 1 contains user control up until cell 14 which is the last cell in a row. Which is why var i = 1 as first iteration and not 0.

Comment: @nickgowdy what i am pointing out is that you are concatenation it as _ctl01 isntead of _ctl0 or _ctl1

Comment: @HatSoft Ok so what do you suggest? I removed the if condition and its changing the next column and not the correct column.

Comment: Bhai all I am saying is you will have a ctrl with 0 for that you don't need to concat with i

Comment: I ended up using another integer value and subtracting that from I and concatenating it to my jquery string. A bit messy but it does what I need it to do. Thanks anyway it helped me see the problem.

Comment: separate the number part and increment that then concatenate it back into your string.

Comment: "ctl00_PageContent_freight_rate_column_chaair_r28_ctl00_txtPercentage" is an example of an ID I was trying to access. See how it starts as 00 . The sequence would of been 01, 02, 03. Hence why that if condition has those strings.

Comment: please show the generated xml in you question above that show these id's